# How to prove that $f(x)$ is much less than $g(x)$?

Tags: limits, inequality, functional-inequalities

In order to prove that $f(x) \ll g(x)$, can I prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$?

Just to clarify my question, I need to prove that $\dfrac{x}{\log(x)-\log(2^t)} \ll \dfrac{x}{4}$, where $t$ is a constant and $x > 2^t$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x)<<g(x)$?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili In this case, I mean f(x) is much smaller than g(x).

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh This is not a rigorous definition, so it’s not clear what it would mean to prove that this holds.

Comment: Here's a thought: what if $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = kx$ where $k$ is a positive constant that you would consider "much smaller" than $1$? Then the limit is $k \neq 0$.

Comment: @AlexMine  I've just updated the question to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: The limit condition $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ (where $c$ is a point of interest) is sometimes taken as the *definition* of "$f(x) \ll g(x)$ near $c$"

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh Do you mean $f(x)=o(g(x))$ by $f(x) \ll g(x)$?

Comment: @Gary I mean f(x) is much smaller than g(x).

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh But that is not a rigorous mathematical concept. For example, is $f(x)=x$ *much smaller* than $g(x)=x\log\log x$ or just a *little bit smaller*? Can you see what I mean?

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh "$f(x)$ is much smaller than $g(x)$" doesn't mean anything! You need to say what **exactly** means $f(x) \ll g(x)$.

Comment: I get the feeling we are banging our heads against a brick wall here.